# Error: invalid merkle root | Error in XDPoS Consensus | fork of go-ethereum

Tags: private-blockchain

Block Synchronisation failed in code :- https://github.com/XinFinOrg/XDPoS-TestNet-Apothem

ERROR[03-23|19:47:12]

#### BAD BLOCK

Chain config: {ChainID: 1151 Homestead: 1 DAO:  DAOSupport: false EIP150: 2 EIP155: 3 EIP158: 3 Byzantium: 4 Constantinople:  Engine: XDPoS}

Number: 2700
Hash: 0x9693b2cfa2f4a4b9ebb7368b4629e75d5fd286040c806f03446c811555f3b931

Error: invalid merkle root (remote: 7f6ce3e89e5c8441a51920db3b9952b0fc3fd50b6193b8f664693fdcc77ea53e local: 49e1c55746d5936711d5cb9039131f060221698c88aac79b5b759ad2940b3f10)

#

WARN [03-23|19:47:12] Synchronisation failed, dropping peer    peer=b7f2b3742ffc19db err="retrieved hash chain is invalid"

Answer (score 0):

**Update geth** to the latest version. I had a similar problem because BSC had a hard fork